# Nodemon does not auto restart

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I have installed nodemon (onto to project directory or globally) but it does not auto restart when I make changes to my code and save it. The terminal in vs code shows '[nodemon] restarting due to changes...' but it just stuck there when I saved my changes.

Had tried different versions of nodemon and reinstall my nodejs but still doesn't work.

This is my package.json and the directory:

> ..\mainfolder\Assignment_1\package.json

> ..\mainfolder\Assignment_1\app.js

```
{
  "name": "assignment_1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "user1",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.18"
  }
}
```

Comment: There may be a lot of things causing this. Can you share your package.json? Also what is the name and place in the folder structure of your main file?

Comment: hi George, i have added above the structure as requested

Comment: It seems fine, maybe something else in your app.js is preventing the server to reach the listen function call. nodemon is pretty straighforward, if your config is ok then it is probably code related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows users like me, I have added in User Variable the following value for PATH variable:

> %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem;

Restarts VS code and it works for me!